# SQL Query for copy a column from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Facing problem to create SQL query to copy table1 column entry into table2 column entry.

Scenario is,

**City** is a table with following attributes,

- City_Id
- latitude
- longitude
- Active

**Venue** is a table with following attributes,

- V_id
- City_Id
- lat
- long

I want to copy all the  **latitude & longitude** into **lat & long** respectively  where **lat & long**  should be NULL and when city is Active = 1 and c.city_id = v.city_id.
But there are multiple city_id exists in Venue and accordingly I need to copy this.

It will be great help if someone helps me to build a query for this.

Comment: read about `update ... join ... set ... where ...`

Comment: copy all the latitude & longitude ..  where lat & long should be NULL , i suppose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement with `JOIN`

```
UPDATE Venue
INNER JOIN City ON City.City_Id = Venue.City_Id
SET Venue.lat = City.latitude, Venue.long = City.longitude
WHERE City.Active = 1 AND (Venue.lat IS NULL OR Venue.long IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `UPDATE` query with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE Venue AS v
JOIN City AS c ON v.city_id = c.city_id
SET v.lat = c.latitude, v.long = c.longitude
WHERE c.active = 1 AND v.lat IS NULL AND v.long IS NULL
```

Comment: Can I use "select" statement in "IN" statement as I want to update venues which are upcoming only so.

Comment: You can, but `JOIN` is usually more efficient in MySQL.